# Can't use number as key in Typescript Map?

Tags: typescript, dictionary

In a class:

```
private stuff: Map<number, string> = new Map();

...

this.stuff[aNumber] = "hello";
```

Gives this error:

> Element implicitly has an `any` type because expression of type `number` can't be used to index type `Map<number, string>`.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type `number` was found on type `Map<number, string>`

This makes no sense to me. Why doesn't `Map<number, string>` declare an index signature with a parameter of type `number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Map` is not using indexer - it's using get/set methods.

```
let foo: Map<number, string> = new Map();
foo.set(2, "something");
let some = foo.get(2);
```

What you could do is use `number: string` custom map object

```
let bar: { [key: number]: string } = {};
bar[1] = "some";
bar["sl"] = "some" // error
```

Please see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcECyBDADgHgHYFcC2ARiAE4A0EAzmMQJZYDmAfBALwRYgDuy6AFAJQBuAFCwYAOgrheAJnIAiCjDzgAFnXryhw0JCUrW0OOPrSZ2neAgEUxRAG8IAbQDWIAJ6JchEgF1EVLQMEAC+hvYhIjbETgCMvoaKyiDyUbZOisDyCWxJKvIQAPSFECTEMMRAA).

Comment: Ah ok, interesting choice! I guess it is to work around some Javascript insanity.

Comment: Of course you could create you own `type CustomMap = { [key: number]: string }` if you are going to reuse it throughout the project.